# jQuery DOM element not defined AFTER page load? (Magento 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I am working in Magento 2 with jQuery and I have the following code:

```
require(["jquery"], function($) {
    var productCarousel = $('.product-carousel-slideshow');
    console.log(productCarousel);
}
```

The element logs to the console as expected, however once the page is loaded I can't do anything with the element, and if I type productCarousel in to the console it is not defined, what could cause this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) *"once the page is loaded I can't do anything with the element"* Show us where and how you're trying to do something with it. *"if I type productCarousel in to the console it is not defined"* Of course not, it's not a global, it's a local scoped **only** to that `require` callback. You could access it from the console if you were paused on a breakpoint within that function, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The productCarousel is defined locally to the require callback, just move the definition globally and you will be able to access it after the load.

Answer (score 0):

If you are overriding magento module then you can simple change in the file Path **app/design/frontend/vendor name/theme name/Module name/requirejs-config.js**. If You Have created custom module then **app/code/Vendor Name/custom Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
   paths: {            
     'Owlcarousel' : 'VendorName_ModuleName/js/owl.carousel.min'     
  },   
  shim: {
    'Owlcarousel': {
        deps: ['jquery']
     }
  }
}
```

Script for phtml:

```
 <script>
   require([
      'jquery',
      'Owlcarousel'
     ], function ($, Owlcarousel) {
       $('#.product-carousel-slideshow-<?php echo $productsliderId;?>').owlCarousel(<?php echo ($block->getAllOptions())?>);
   });
```